# IAM Policy not working when condition block is added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I'm experiencing a strange issue regarding IAM policy!
I want to limit RDS access to specific IAM roles for different environments, the policy works fine until I add conditions!!

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "rds:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "rds:db-tag/Environment": "dev"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "RdsAccess"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

[Screenshoot of RDS service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lntKe.png)

However, when I remove the condition, the policy works just fine.
You can see AWS services' conditions keys from the official AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html

Comment: Does the rds instance have a tag?

Comment: @Paolo yes it does.

Comment: You need to explicitly grant the describedbclusters:* and describedbinstances:* because tag based conditions do not work on these kind of actions.

Comment: @luk2302 I have tried that also, didn't work...

Comment: What did you try, how did that not work? The grants to those two actions must not have a condition on them. What did your policy look like in that case and what error did you get?

Comment: No, I tried with the condition because I need to show only the databases from one specific environment, not all of them.

Comment: That is not possible, in most / all AWS services. The list/listing type of actions can only be granted or not, no in between middle ground of listing just *some*. You can restrict actions on individual instances based on conditions, but you cannot hide them during listing. Not 100% sure for rds but I would assume this is the case here as well.

Comment: Yes, what I need is: to manage RDS databases from one environment, and only see RDS databases from other environments

Comment: Which, imo, still need a condition!

Comment: Might be true but does not matter if AWS simply does not support that.

Comment: IAM policy conditions do not cause resource lists, e.g. the output from RDS DescribeDBInstances, to be filtered. That action has no supported conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The condition value needs to be

`"rds:db-tag/Environment": ["dev"]`

In other words the tag key values are expected in an array.

Added reference,
[image]

Comment: my friend... yes I am sure!

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? The [policy grammar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html) says: "If the element takes an array (marked with [ and ]) but only one value is included, the brackets are optional." So, if it did allow an array of values (which is not clear at present) and you only supplied one, the brackets would be optional.

Comment: added evidence. If you do not supply an array value then you need to omit the space after the resolve operator in case of a single key value. So that would be
`"rds:db-tag/Environment":"dev"`

Comment: @jarmod ${TagKey} refers to the Key and here the solution I posted refers to how you provide the value in the policy since providing the tag key was done correctly by the OP, do not see how your questions are relevant to this answer?

Comment: I'll try this if I have time. I would be surprised if "you need to omit the space after the resolve operator [presume you mean the name-separator colon] in case of a single key value". In the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), any amount of insignificant whitespace is allowed either side of name separators.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Hey, furydrive, @jarmod is correct, if we have a single key value, the brackets are optional. However, I've tried also with brackets, but same result...